# How to create application launcher on Centos/SL 7.2 64 bit?

Tags: centos

I asked simple question.
I didnt know to create application launcher on Centos/SL 7.2 64 bit after I installed binary application from tarball.Any ideas? I used GNOME not KDE

Comment: What desktop environment do you have installed?  (KDE, Gnome, etc)

Comment: In KDE you can right click in the desktop widget and go to create new -> link to application.

Comment: I used GNOME not KDE. I want to launch seamonkey 2.46 after Installed it from binary tarball.

Comment: You just need to create a `*.desktop` file for it.  Simply adapting an example should take you two minutes.  You can take a look at http://askubuntu.com/a/112259/585715 for example.

Comment: I will try it and put it on gnome menu.I have been created softlink on /home/user/Desktop. I can execute it without run it from terminal.